# How to encode mysql data in JSON format?

Tags: php, json

code:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    error_reporting(0);
    include("config.php");
    $sql = "select * from category";
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $data[] = array(
                        'category' => $row['category_name'],
                        'image' => $row['file_s']
                    );
    } 
    echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

In this code I have convert mysql data in json format using `json_encode` function. It display look like as below:

```
[
  {
    "category": "cap",
    "image": "Cap-01.png"
  },
  {
    "category": "hair",
    "image": "Hair Color-01.png"
  }
]
```

But I want it another way like:

```
[
cap  {
       "image": "Cap-01.png"
     },
hair {
       "image": "Hair Color-01.png"
     }
]
```

So how can I do this? Please help me.

Thank You

Comment: Your desired output is not valid JSON, please edit.  Check via e.g. https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Answer (score 1):

use category name as index

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $data[$row['category_name']] = array(
        'image' => $row['file_s']
    );
}
echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: didn't get you? Please describe a bit more.

Comment: If I use `$data[$row['category_name']]` so what am I pass in json_encode function